# Android Horizontal Scrolling

Tags: java, android

For Android Horizontal Scrolling ..how can i keep one or two column fixed?? Rest of one or two column others will scroll horizontally... please help me....
I want to keep fixed one column horizontally fixed in Scroll View TableLayout (here...android:id="@+id/tblPVPDetailList")

```
      <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tblPVPDetailHeader2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape" >
            </TableLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tblPVPDetailList"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.27"
                        android:background="@drawable/shape"
                        android:horizontalSpacing="3dip" 
                        >
                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```